# Show full image path D8

Tags: media

I have set a Drupal 8 project into another server with some child directory. This D8 project is working good, But images are not showing due to path missing. E.g

My project is setup:- http://abc.xyz.com/client/development/**project-name**/

but when I was inspecting element then I got image URL:-http://abc.xyz.com/sites/default/files/images.png

I know client/develoment/project-name/ path is missing into the image path. May you let me know how to get full image path display?

Full path must show:-http://abc.xyz.com/client/development/**project-name**/sites/default/files/images.png

Thanks

Comment: In what context you want image url? Are you in custom module ? Twig template?

Comment: Want to display image in the browser.Bcoz project already is done but images are not displayed.

Comment: Do anything change in default/settings.php page?

Comment: Images are inside the body or part of fields, you have to give more information otherwise the question is very broad.

Comment: Images are inside into the body.

Comment: If images are inside body then they already have a path. Drupal is not generating the path, so you can't change the path. You should edit your content or solve it in the webserver level.

Answer (score 0):

Images are hardlinked inside the body field.

One way to correct it is to do a search and replace inside the database.

Perhaps also [pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) can help correct the problem with broken images.

- add pathologic support to your desired text formats (congig > content authoring > text formats)
- make sure you check  *Correct URLs with Pathologic*

when visiting a page pathologic should correct those broken images